# SAP ui5 detail Page layout

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, page-layout

i want to implement this type of layout in one module shown in the given picture can you please help me.

[image]

layout

Comment: Please try sth on your own and show it here in order to get help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to implement a split-screen layout with an overlapping header.

Please consult with your UX Experts and take a look at the [Flexible Column Layout](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/) to select a Layout compliant with the Fiori Guidelines.

Then take the [Flexible Column Layout sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout) as starting point for your development.